# How do I ensure mobile apps doesn't steal user/password calling my REST API

Tags: android, ios, rest, security, windows-phone

We're developing a REST based API that developers would call from their mobile apps, e.g. google play apps.

How can we make sure that the app developer doesn't steal the users user/pass by storing them or sending them to "EvilServer".

If we do not trust the app developers, does a technical solution to this problem exist?

Could one solution be to have our own trusted authentication app on the native platform and let app developers use it to authenticate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend is to first remove the ability for a third-party application to log a user to your service using his credentials, so there is no reason for an app to ask for the user's credentials in the first place.

I would instead provide an [`OAuth`](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified) authentication endpoint (take a look at the [server-side flow](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified#web-server-apps)) to third-party developers in order for them to use **your** authentication service to register and authenticate users in their app. This is interesting because users have to be redirected to your authentication endpoint when they log in, so there is no chance a third-party application can have access to their credentials at any point.

However, nothing prevents the developer of an evil app from creating a fake form requiring the user to provide sensitive informations in order to log them in, such as an email and a password.

In this case, you can do two things :

- First, educate your users (e.g when they create their account) not to provide their credentials on any other website than yours. This is typically done by banks and insurance companies.
- Implement [`Multi-Factor Authentication`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) to add another layer of security to your authentication process. Most web companies such as Google or Twitter allow you to require that while providing your usual credentials when logging in, you are still required to validate the login process using an *out-of-band* medium. They typically achieve this by sending you a PIN code via SMS on your phone that you must input on a web page to finish the login process.
  As such, if someone tries to log into one of your user's account, it will fail unless they have also access to the user phone.

Comment: I've been reading up on OAuth, and there seems to be different views if it is a good solution or not (http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/26/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/) and some more.. I've looked at this solution (https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm) and it looks good. So still not sure what solution to choose but I've gotten a bit further. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Seems interesting, it basically exchanges key pairs through a QR code and removes the need for a keyboard. I'll take a deeper look, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth attempts to solve this problem by sending the user off to a provider to authenticate before bringing them back to the original site or app. This is how the "Log in with Facebook" and "Log in with Twitter" systems work.

There's a handy diagram at http://www.quora.com/How-does-Login-with-Facebook-option-work-on-third-party-websites that shows how the requests are passed back and forth.